# PHP/MySQL - Convert database value to MD5, then shrink to a portion of that value?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I am using PHP and MySQL to create a string from a value and later compare it to a MD5 hash of the same value.

For instance, in MySQL i have a string value: `somerandomvalue`

In PHP I get that string value and transfer it to a local variable to hold the string value: `$prdAlias`

I transform the string value to a MD5 hash value:

```
$prdAlias = md5($prdAlias);
```

Then I take only the first 6 characters of that value for use later:

```
$prdAlias = mb_substr($prdAlias, 0, 6);
```

*LATER*

I have the first 6 characters of the MD5 value, I call it: `$prdAlias`

Now in MySQL i want to compare `$prdAlias` to the value that i started off with: `somerandomvalue`. To do that, I must convert the value in the database to a MD5 hash then take only the first 6 characters of the hash and compare that to `$prdAlias`

So I have a prepared statement:

```
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("
    SELECT alias
    FROM `products`
    WHERE alias = ?
"))
{
    ... ETC
}
```

My question now is within this statement, how could i convert the alias value to MD5 and take only the first 6 characters of that to use in the WHERE clause?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: I am currently running a while loop and checking for the value by processing each row until a match is found... This is not ideal with thousands of rows.

Comment: Er, why is your original `somerandomvalue` stored in the db?

Comment: @PaulGregory There is no need for it to be secure, it is not confidential or a password of any sort, just a value i need to use to compare part of the page name so that i can suck the relative info out of the database when a user visits the url :)

Comment: A truncated MD5 is usually used for security, and more usually the MD5 is stored while the original string is not. Whilst it does happen to generate a non-sequential identifier, it is not going to be unique. Especially if `somerandomvalue` genuinely is random. I think you need to seriously reconsider your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the mysql `MD5()` function to do this on the database server:

```
WHERE LEFT(MD5{alias), 6) = ?
```

but that would still require a full table scan, so would basically be identical to your while loop. If you want this to be fast, you need an index. I don’t think mysql has computed indexes that means you will have to add a column for the first six characters of the md5 of alias and compare against that.

I would personally store the whole hash and do a `LIKE "123456%"` though. Just a gut feeling that might be smarter in the long run. On the other hand if you only store the first six characters, you could add a unique key on that column and detect collisions early on.

Comment: Very informative, thanks so much! I am trying to speed things up so it looks like creating the value when the product is created might be the best option, i need the original value so I was just trying to find a way to make use of what i already have.

Comment: I can see why you would want that, but this is just one of those cases where you will have to accept redundancy for performance’s sake.

Comment: I have the need for duplicate products. I have keyword rich urls based on the product information. I am using the hash as part of the url in order to create unique urls for each product that i can use as "keywords" to seek the corresponding product out of the database ;) I agree though and have been thinking about this for some time, just trying to better the process. In any case your response has been most helpful, thank you again!